# RSA encryption from Flex client and Corresponding Decryption from Web service

Tags: c#, wcf, apache-flex, actionscript-3, public-key-encryption

I'm having a problem setting up RSA encryption/decryption mechanism between flex client and web service written in c#. The idea is this: I'll encrypt some text from flex and then decrypt it from web service.  I'm using as3crypto library from google. It is encrypting/decrypting text properly. I also have the code on the web service side to encrypt/decrypt properly. My problem is synchronizing them - basically sharing the public key to flex and keeping the private key to the web service.

My flex "encrypt" function takes modulus and exponent of RSA to do text encryption, so how do i get these modulus and exponent attributes from the web service's RSACryptoServiceProvider, so they speak the same standard. 
I tried the 
RSAKeyInfo.Modulus
RSAKeyInfo.Exponent
from the web service and fed them to the flex client.
After doing encryption on flex I took the cipher text and fed it to decrypt method on web service, but it is giving me "bad data" error message.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle hPubKey, Byte[] key, Int32 dwFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
   at Microsoft.Samples.Security.PublicKey.App.RSADecrypt(Byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, Boolean DoOAEPPadding) in C:\Users
\Me\Desktop\After Release\5-24-2011-webServiceCrypto\publickeycryptography\CS\PublicKeyCryptography\PublicKey.cs:line 219
Encryption failed.
```

How do i make sure they are both using the same byte 64 or 128 byte encryption . ie the input from flex should fit to what is expected by the web service RSACryptoServiceProvider's decrypt method.
(I'm assuming the size might be a problem, may be it's not - i'm lost)

Here is the code, first flex client followed by web service c# code

```
private function encrypt():void {
                var rsa:RSAKey = RSAKey.parsePublicKey(getModulus(), getExponent());
                trace("Modulus Lenght: " + getModulus().length);
                trace("Exponent Lenght : " + getExponent().length);
                var data:ByteArray = getInput();  //returns byteArray of plainText
                var dst:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
                rsa.encrypt(data, dst, data.length);
                trace("Enc Data: " + dst.toString() );
                currentResult = Hex.fromArray(dst);
                encryptedText = currentResult;
                trace("Encrypted:: " + currentResult);
            }

            //For testing purposes
            private function decrypt():void {
                var rsa:RSAKey = RSAKey.parsePrivateKey(getModulus(), getExponent(), getPrivate(), getP(), getQ(), getDMP1(), getDMQ1(), getCoeff());
                var data:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(encryptedText);
                trace("Byte array: " + data.toString());
                var dst:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
                rsa.decrypt(data, dst, data.length);
                decryptedText = Hex.fromArray(dst);
                trace("Decrypted text: " + Hex.toString(decryptedText));
            }
```

And web service part is as follows:

```
       try
        {
            //Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
            UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

            //Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data.
            byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("Data to Encrypt");
            byte[] encryptedData;
            byte[] decryptedData;

            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate
            //public and private key data.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                //Pass the data to ENCRYPT, the public key information 
                //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false),
                //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, RSA.ExportParameters(false), false);
                //Pass the data to DECRYPT, the private key information 
                //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(true),
                //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                decryptedData = RSADecrypt(encryptedData, RSA.ExportParameters(true), false);
                //Display the decrypted plaintext to the console. 
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nDecrypted plaintext: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedData));
            }
        }

static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {

                //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
                //toinclude the public key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                //later.  
                encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return null;
        }

    }


 static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Modulus Lenghth :" + RSAKeyInfo.Modulus.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Exponent Length :" + RSAKeyInfo.Exponent.Length);
            byte[] decryptedData;
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                //Import the RSA Key information. This needs
                //to include the private key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                //later.  
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return decryptedData;
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            return null;
        }

    }
```

I'm not quite sure if this RSA set up is the way to go... 
Any kinda comment / advice/ or recommended solution is welcome,
thanks guys

Comment: I removed the Webservices tag and replaced it w/ Public-Key-Encryption; as that seemed more a important way to tag this question.

Comment: Encryption is useless when the user has access to the key. You will never be able to implement a solution that is more secure then SSL, so you may as well just use that...

Comment: Thanks flextras. @drkstr- the user has the public key and doesn't know the private key, so how is it useless? And my web services are exposed via https, so certain level of security is achieved by that.

Comment: Now I'm curious... Is this some sort of regulatory shenanigans requiring encryption?  I could imagine a situation where the client encrypts the data like you want and sends to the web server.  But the web server doesn't have the decryption key.  Some other machine occasionally grabs that data and decrypts it.

Comment: It's useless because client-side encryption only hides data from the person who already has it. @Marc Even still, it would be much better to run the encryption server-side. The only time client-side encryption makes sense is when SSL is unavailable, or if the data needs to be stored locally prior to being sent to the server (like an off-line mode). Since the data already exists unencrypted on the client, and SSL will encrypt anything sent over the wire, there is simply no need to run any kind of encryption client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka! Eureka! I got it.

The problem was after decryption from web service, the encrypted byte array missed 0's in between, so that when changed to string it gets unreadable '????????' text. So I just put paddWithZeros() function to pad the decrypted byte array with 0's between bytes and it worked.

Thanks Kevin, your solution gave me an insight into what things I should consider. So during decrypting I specify parameter fOAEP as false, so it would use PKCS#1 for padding (making both libraries use the same standard).

```
RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding); // DoOAEPPadding = false
```

another error that i was getting is Bad Data exception. This was fixed when i shared the RSA cryptoServiceProvider's parameters (modulus and exponent) to actionScript methods.

I also changed the byte[] array of c# RSA attributes (like Modulus n, Exponent e, Private d..etc) to hexa string so that I'd be able to share with as3crypto library.

I'd love to share what worked for me; save others some time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.hurlant.crypto.Crypto;
            import com.hurlant.crypto.rsa.RSAKey;
            import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.ICipher;
            import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.IPad;
            import com.hurlant.util.Hex;

            private var currentResult:String;
            private var encryptedText:String;
            private var decryptedText:String;

            private function encrypt(plainText:String):String {
                var rsa:RSAKey = RSAKey.parsePublicKey(getModulus(), getExponent());
                var data:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(plainText));  //returns byteArray of plainText
                var dst:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
                rsa.encrypt(data, dst, data.length);
                currentResult = Hex.fromArray(dst);
                encryptedText = currentResult;
                trace ("Cipher: " + currentResult);
                return currentResult;
            }

            private function getInput():ByteArray {
                return null;
            }

            private function getModulus():String {
                return "b6a7ca9002b4df39af1ed39251a5d"; //read this value from web service.
            }

            private function getExponent():String {
                return "011"; //read this value from web service.
            }

            //For debugging and testing purposes
            // private function decrypt(cipherText:String):String {
                // var rsa:RSAKey = RSAKey.parsePrivateKey(getModulus(), getExponent(), getPrivate(), getP(), getQ(), getDMP1(), getDMQ1(), getCoeff());
                // var data:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(cipherText);
                // var dst:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
                // rsa.decrypt(data, dst, data.length);
                // decryptedText = Hex.fromArray(dst);
                     //trace('decrypted : ' + decryptedText);
                // return Hex.toString(decryptedText);
            // }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:VBox >
        <s:Button label="Encrypt Text" click="encrypt('my plain text')" />
        <s:Button label="Decrypt Text" click="decrypt({encryptedText})" />
    </mx:VBox>
</s:Application>
```

And the web service part of decryption looks like this:

```
 static public string RSADecrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] DataToDecrypt = StringToByteArray(cipherText);
        bool DoOAEPPadding = false;
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = keyInfo.getKey();
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo); 
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            byte[] paddedOutput = paddWithZeros(decryptedData); //to sync with as3crypto
            return (ByteConverter.GetString(paddedOutput));

        }catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            //handle error
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'll do some reading about padding schemes for RSA, see if there is any misconception.

Thanks

Comment: your answer relies on your paddWithZeros method which isn't provided

Comment: The problem here is with the conversion from a byte array to a string.  The it looks like the actionscript is using an 8-bit like ascii but the c# is using Unicode.  If the correct encoding is used there will be no need to pad with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I use as3crypto and JAVA web-services.  Here are some thoughts:

a. I generated my public and private RSA keys via openssl

b.  My client loads the public .cer file at application startup (if you just hardcoded them in from the generated key that works too).

```
var pemString : String = new String(data.target.data);
var x509Cert : X509Certificate = new X509Certificate(pemString);
var publicRSAKey : RSAKey = x509Cert.getPublicKey();
```

c. Encrypt my strings via

```
var inputByteArray : ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(inputString));
var outputByteArray : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
appSettingsModel.publicRSAKey.encrypt(inputByteArray, outputByteArray, inputByteArray.length);
```

d. I didn't write the JAVA side of things but you aren't using JAVA anyways. I know that as3crypto uses PKCS1 padding by default:

RSAKEY.as

```
private function _encrypt(op:Function, src:ByteArray, dst:ByteArray, length:uint, pad:Function, padType:int):void {
            // adjust pad if needed
            if (pad==null) pad = pkcs1pad;
```

This can be changed but I haven't tried it yet.  Based on your code it looks like you might be trying to decrypt with OAEP scheme, but I can't tell how you are setting that bool.  You may want to take a look at what padding scheme is being used with the bool as false and try to change one side or the other to match padding strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Seems overly complicated.  I've worked on some high security systems before, but this is ludicrous.  Why would you need this kind of level of encryption at the text being sent unless you don't want the user to know the text he just inputted?

Just use a strong SSL key (256bit is max for IE6, you could use 512 but only compatible with newer browsers) for the actual transfer protocol (I imagine HTTP) with a binary data format (AMF) and everything should be fine.  I doubt your system is that important to leverage the use of encrypting text.

Comment: Jax, but did i mention that I'm encrypting user given input? The data that's being encrypted is not user's input. It's certain info that should be encrypted end to end - client to server. The concept is not overly complex. In Public key cryptography it doesn't matter what library/framework u use as long as u use my public key to encrypt. My question is, how can i encrypt in flex and decrypt in c#? I know there are security issues associated with flex, but let's not go in to those.

Comment: @Rose There is no practical need to encrypt data client-side. If the data exists unencrypted on the client side, then it's already compromised to whoever is on the other end. The data is encrypted when sent over SSL, so there is no need to encrypt any data until it reaches the server. The bottom line is that client is public, and should never be trusted, encrypted or not. You would do better to focus on server side security and authentication.

Comment: If you're using a secure protocol, IT IS being encrypted end to end.  My point is, encrypting it a second time will not give you any value, and will in all probability slow down your system (especially if you have a lot of data) because the encryption/decryption process on flash is not native.  There's a reason for that, because it's not needed.  The only reason AS3Crypto exists is for use with Sockets for new kinds of protocols not given in Flash.